# How much time it takes to upload a theme on Wordpress.org repository

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made myself a wordpress theme and I want to submit it to Wordpress Theme Repository.
Does anybody know what requirements do I have to follow besides the Theme Unit Test. The theme will be easily accepted or it has to be approved firstly? How much time the whole process can take aproximately. Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-your-theme-to-the-wordpressorg-repository?replies=1) out! It might be helpful for what you need!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something which can not be predicted, and is not about writing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from WordPress Plugin development it should take about 3 days to get approved and listed on the repository.  You need to be familiar with their revisioning system which is SVN.    Other than that it is pretty painless